# vim keystroke for \ type hotkeys?

Tags: vim, hotkeys

What do I type in i, n, and v mode to do say the following hotkey?

\sd
\sf

Also I am using this plugin in cygwin?

This is the [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556) and the hotkeys [Warning PDF](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-perl/perl-hot-keys.pdf) that I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

For \sd to get a `do {} while` with the cursor between the braces:

```
:imap \sd do {} while<ESC>hhhhhhi
:nmap \sd ado {} while<ESC>hhhhhhi
:vmap \sd ado {} while<ESC>hhhhhhi
```

With this, I guess you should be able to fill in the rest as well.

Comment: What do I actually type on the key board to initiate this hotkey. For example I learned the ^C is ctrl+shift+C what is \sd? Alt Meta? If I type in \sd in normal more on s it substitutes character under cursor with d.

Comment: There is no single hotkey, it's a sequence of keys. In this case, you actually type backslash, s, d. When you add the mapping, it will overrule any mapping that came before.

Comment: but I installed http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556 but these hotkeys still don't work

Comment: Go to normal mode and type in the commands I gave, see if they work. If they do, you probably didn't install your plugin correctly. If they don't, maybe you didn't type the keys fast enough, or some other strange thing is going on ...

Comment: This plugin works fine in gvim the menus shows up properly and I can click on menu items which have the \sd hot key. Why can't I do this in the terminal one? \lps says it will load the menus.

Comment: Well, menus aren't available in the terminal. Only in GUI-based vims, like gvim. In the terminal, I'm afraid you'll just have to type the key sequences.
(In fact if you look inside `perl-support.vim` you'll see the definition of `lps` is inside a big `if has("gui_running")` block.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding

```
filetype plugin on
```

in ~/.vimrc